# Percentage of a Number

Tags: java

So I'm a little frustrated with how many times I've tried this.
I'm using # / 100 = % * Balance = Fine here, yet for some reason always results to 0. Note that this uses an external API.

```
double fine = (getConfig().getBoolean("fineispercentage") == true ? getConfig().getInt("fine") / 100 * count * econ.getBalance(event.getPlayer().getName()) : econ.getBalance(event.getPlayer().getName()) - (econ.getBalance(event.getPlayer().getName()) - count * getConfig().getInt("fine")));
```

When true, always results to 0. When false, it goes the way it's supposed to, which is subtract an amount depending on the count.

Comment: What type is the amount?

Comment: The type of the amount is a double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (not tested):

```
double fine = (getConfig().getBoolean("fineispercentage") == true ? getConfig().getInt("fine") / 100.0 * count * econ.getBalance(event.getPlayer().getName()) : econ.getBalance(event.getPlayer().getName()) - (econ.getBalance(event.getPlayer().getName()) - count * getConfig().getInt("fine")));
```

The trick is to divide by `100.0` (double), not `100` (int)

Comment: I never thought it'd be that simple. Thanks!

Comment: This is the right answer, but I prefer 100d or 100f to force datatypes. It guarantees you get the type you are expecting.

Comment: @Mike 100.0 absolutely guarantees double. See the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2): "A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter D or d". Unless there are very good reasons, usually involving extremely large arrays, double should be used rather than float.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `getInt` does actually return an integer, it looks like you're doing integer division, giving you `0`.

Divide `getConfig().getInt("fine")` by `100d` instead of `100`:

```
double fine = (getConfig().getBoolean("fineispercentage") == true ? getConfig().getInt("fine") / 100.0 * count * econ.getBalance(event.getPlayer().getName()) : econ.getBalance(event.getPlayer().getName()) - (econ.getBalance(event.getPlayer().getName()) - count * getConfig().getInt("fine")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `getConfig().getInt()` returns an `int`, this java division:

```
getConfig().getInt("fine) / 100
```

Will do an integer division, and produce an `int` result, which will truncate any decimal part, so any value of "fine" 0-99 will result in a zero.  The fix is this:

```
getConfig().getInt("fine) / 100d
```

Adding the "d" to 100 makes the 100 a `double` value, which will perform a double division, keeping the decimal part.